# Superconductivity vs. energy gap

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, transport-phenomena

Many textbooks derive the single-particle excitation energy gap from the BCS mean-field hamiltonian, and then stop there, implying that this gap is sufficient for superconductivity.

To be frank, I cannot see why a gap implies superconductivity.

Superconductivity is a transport phenomenon. But the BCS mean-field hamiltonian is just a static hamiltonian; it is not directly connected to transport, right?

Comment: A good textbook should also derive the electromagnetic response from the BCS theory. Also, the gap is not essential for superconductivity. For example, a nodal d-wave SC does not have quasiparticle energy gap, but still superconducting.

Comment: Well, first of all the spectral gap explains the specific heat as a function of temperature. Moreover, you can compute the magnetic susceptibility by using the static mean field Hamiltonian and you should be able to observe the Meissner effect, if I'm not mistaken